# Need a query or transaction to export data into a set format

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to export data from a database into a set format so that it can be interpreted by myob correctly. I have the exporting function working great and I have half worked out the sql query but am having trouble with how to put it all together.

The following is a simple example to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

```
$sql = "SELECT (CONCAT(PICKUPID,DROPOFFID) AS ITEM), 
               (CONCAT(Rego, Pickup, Dropoff, booker, date) AS Description) 
        FROM booking, myob";
```

The issue is that I need to pull the pickup and dropoff /ID out of the myob table in reference to what is in the booking table.

**booking Table Columns**

- Rego
- Pickup
- Dropoff
- Date
- booker

**myob Table Columns**

- MYOBID (where MYOBID = PICKUPID OR DROPOFFID)
- Address (where Address = Dropoff or Pickup)

I am hoping to do this in an SQL query or a PL/SQL transaction but I'm having trouble getting my head around it. Any help would be appreciated (hope the questions not to confusing)

*Data in Tables***

*booking*

```
Rego , Pickup , Dropoff , Date    , booker

123,    bris,     sydn,      1/2/12,    barry
```

*myob*

```
MYOBID , Address

Q,        bris

N,        sydn
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ITEM   , Description

QN,       123 bris sydn 1/2/12 barry
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of some data in the tables and what the expected result would be? I'm having a hard time understanding the question.

Comment: added in an example to the question to better explain

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) the two tables.
You may also find some more practical information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).
Please come back to us if you are still stuck after reading these.

Also, I see little advantage in CONCAT'ing your fields at query time, I think you'd better leave the formatting out the output to your application layer. Of course, this is probably an overkill if all you are trying to achieve is a quick-and-dirty one-time export.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I originally though bout using a join but the problem is that I need to implement the myobid field twice as I need it for both the pickup and dropoff location and i couldn't get the field to output the ids for both locations. also this is just a one time quick and dirty export. Thanks

Comment: You can JOIN `myob` to `booking` twice in the same query, once for each of `booking.Pickup` and `booking.Dropoff` fields. In the second JOIN, just treat `myob` as if it was another table, but you will need to create an alias for it the second time. E.g: `SELECT t1.id, t2.aField, t2_again.aField FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t2.id = t1.t2_id_one) JOIN t2 AS t2_again ON (t2_again.id = t2.t1_id_two)`